# "ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2" when using ConvLSTM2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a pre-trained model which has output of shape (20,7,7,256)

I reshape this output to `(None,20,7,7,256)` using `tf.keras.layers.Reshape((20,7,7,256))` and then feed it to a `ConvLSTM2D` layer

```
x = ConvLSTM2D(filters = 256,kernel_size = 3,strides=(1,1),padding='same',
               data_format = 'channels_last',return_state = True,
               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=16))(x)
```

But I get this error every time I run the above code.

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in convolution_internal(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name, call_from_convolution)
    957     channel_index = 1 if data_format.startswith("NC") else n + 1
    958 
--> 959   strides = _get_sequence(strides, n, channel_index, "strides")
    960   dilations = _get_sequence(dilations, n, channel_index, "dilations")
    961 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in _get_sequence(value, n, channel_index, name)
     73     value = list(value)
     74   else:
---> 75     raise ValueError("{} should be of length 1, {} or {} but was {}".format(
     76         name, n, n + 2, current_n))
     77 

ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2
```

What is causing the problem I do not understand, even though I am giving `strides = (1,1)`?? And what is the solution to this problem?

**EDIT**

THE ERROR WAS NOT IN THIS ConvLSTM2D layer, but it was in the next ConvLSTM2D layer that I added after this one. I used `return_state = True` in this layer but my intention was to use `return_sequences = True` and this was causing the error in the next ConvLSTM2D layer.

The original code is this after changing `return_state` to `return_sequences`

```
x = ConvLSTM2D(filters = 256,kernel_size = 3,
               strides=(1,1),padding='same',return_sequences = True,
               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=16))(x)
x = ConvLSTM2D(filters = 256,kernel_size = 3,
               strides=(1,1),padding='same',return_sequences = False,
               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=16))(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The resolution is specified by the user. Mentioning the resolution here in the answer section for the benefit of the community -

> The error was not in this `ConvLSTM2D` layer, but it was in the next
> `ConvLSTM2D` layer that I added after this one. I used `return_state = True` in this layer but my intention was to use `return_sequences = True`
> and this was causing the error in the next `ConvLSTM2D` layer.
>
> The original code is this after changing `return_state` to
> `return_sequences`

```
x = ConvLSTM2D(filters = 256,kernel_size = 3,
               strides=(1,1),padding='same',return_sequences = True,
               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=16))(x)
x = ConvLSTM2D(filters = 256,kernel_size = 3,
               strides=(1,1),padding='same',return_sequences = False,
               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=16))(x)
```